# Heroku ERROR: Invalid requirement: '_libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge'

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I followed a tutorial on how to post Voila notebooks on Heroku but at the command git push heroku master I get an error as in:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '_libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge' (from line 4 of /tmp/build_869fdf5f/requirements.txt)
remote:        Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?
```

The requiremets were exported from a conda environment.
Please help.

Comment: it looks like there are some issues related to the environment of conda. after I replaced the requirements generated by conda with the same generated by pip and this time the error was  :ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi_1596629847793/work

Comment: Did you try using any buildpack?